# Why does print('a' and 'b') return 'b' in python?

Tags: python, string, boolean

I think understand that print('a' or 'b') returns 'a', since x or y gives x if x is true, which 'a' can be interpreted as? But why does print('a' and 'b') return 'b'?

Comment: @ApplePie the top answer on that question looks correct, but boy is it wordy!

Answer (score 1):

`or` returns the first value if it's truthy, otherwise it returns the second value. Meanwhile, `and` returns the first value if it's falsy, otherwise it returns the second value. This is consistent with the definition of the operators:

```
True or _ = True
False or x = x
True and x = x
False and _ = False
```

Also, all non-empty strings are truthy.